# A question about Ramsey type statements

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, reference-request, ramsey-theory

Suppose we ask for the minimum $R(H)$ s.t every $2-$coloring of the complete graph $K_{R(H)}$ must contain a monochromatic copy of $H$. It is known that $R(H)$ is finite for all $H$. What can be said about $R(H)$ as a function of $H$. Meaning, what types of graphs yield a lower/higher Ramsey number?

Intuitively it seems, for example, that if the number of edges $m = \Theta(n)$ for some class of graphs $H_n$, then $R(H_n)\leq R(K_n)$. This might be wildly wrong though.

Sorry if this is a bit qualitative but any ideas/known results in this general direction would be of help.

Comment: I'm assuming $n$ is fixed. Indeed, $R(K_n, K_n)$ is the maximum Ramsey number among all graphs of order $n$ (i.e. your intuition is correct). Depending on what you choose, the gap will generally be quite wide. As a concrete example, we have $R(K_4, K_4) = 18 > 6 = R(C_4, C_4)$. Of course, Ramsey numbers can also be made essentially as small as desired by picking graphs like $\overline{K_n}$. In general, the sparser the graph, the smaller the Ramsey number will inevitably be. Of course this probably isn't the level of analysis you were looking for, it's just some observations.

Comment: @Paralyzed_by_Time Thanks! Do you happen to know good references for these things by any chance?

Comment: I think what I've stated (and what you inferred) hardly needs a reference, since a monochromatic $n$-clique contains a monochromatic copy of every $n$-vertex graph; hence monochromatic copies of sparser graphs may be forced by coloring a graph *at most* the order needed to force $K_n$. For general resources on Ramsey Theory, I'm partial to Section 8.3 of Doug West's "Intro to Graph Theory," which is succinct and hits many of the highlights (along with many great exercises). For a more complete reference, my personal recommendation would be "Ramsey Theory" by Graham, Rothschild, and Spencer.

Comment: @Paralyzed_by_Time Of course, but is was thinking about other similar cases when $E_1=\Theta(n^2)$ and $E_2 = \Theta(n)$. But thanks for the books recommendations!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer above, I want to explain why $K_n$ gives the highest Ramsey number of all graphs on $n$ vertices. I'll use $R(n)$ to denote $R(K_n)$.

As you stated, Ramsey guaranties that every 2 coloring of $K_{R(n)}$ contains a monochromatic $K_n$. So in particular, since $G$ is a subgraph of $K_n$, every 2-coloring of $K_{R(n)}$ contains a monochromatic G.

So for every graph $G$ such that $V(G)=n$, it follows that $R(G)\le R(n)$.